# Run a remote python script from a local python script and pass some arguments

Tags: python

I have a `remote python script` which has the following code in it:

```
    from os import system
    import sys


    if __name__ == '__main__':

        arg1 = sys.argv[1] // ip address of host
        arg2 = sys.argv[2]

        cmd_txt = "ssh -i pem-file user@" + arg1 + " 'cd /folder1/folder2/ && java -cp jar-file.jar pack1.pack2.py-file -f folder1/folder2/file_" + ts + ".txt'"
        system(cmd_txt)
```

Now I want to run this `remote python script` from a `python script` which is present on my local machine alongwith passing the two arguments to it - `arg1` & `arg2`. So basically my `local python script` will make a call to `remote python script` and pass the two arguments to it. I know how to execute a local python script from another python script but not the remote python script. How can I do this?

**UPDATE:** I executed this script from my local machine which makes a call to remote python script and passes two arguments. When I run this script I get `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)` error:

```
host = [host-ip] #host_ip in string format
args1 = 'str1'
args2 = 'str2'

cmd_txt = "sudo ssh -i pem-file user@" + host + " 'cd folder1/folder2/ && python file1.py "+ args1 +" "+ args2 +"'"
system(cmd_txt)
```

What am I missing in my code above?

Comment: please don't use `os.system`, its superseded for ages by `subprocess`. Also don't use strings as commands, but then lists `["ssh", "-i", path_to_pemfile ...]` to avoid shell escaping issues. This is general advice though, I second Freek's answer for fabric.

Comment: @SteveJessop I know its odd but I am unable to bypass that as it is customer system requirement. So, will `ssh -i pem-file user@" + hostname+ " 'cd folder1/folder2/ && python file1.py "+ args1 +" "+ args2 +"'` be correct?

Comment: @SteveJessop above `args1` and `args2` are the two arguments I want to pass to remote python script and `folder1/folder2/` is the location of the script on remote server

Comment: @SteveJessop I executed the command I have mentioned in the updated section in my post above but I am getting an error which I have mentioned

Comment: Is your pem file actually called "pem-file", and does it connect if you simply type the ssh command on the terminal?

Comment: Any luck with your SSH / python automation work?

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite: SSH and key sync (the client's public key should be in the server's authorized_keys file).

I see that your local command starts with `sudo`. Yet the .pem file will provide the same access to the server regardless if you're connecting from a root or standard account on your local system (different situation if you weren't using the .pem file but the default `${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa`). I recommend making sure the normal local user can make outgoing ssh connections and dropping the `sudo`.

Take a look at the Fabric package (pip install fabric). It really rocks at what you want to achieve. The big advantage is that Fabric provides a good abstraction over the os or subprocess statements and allows you to run server-side commands from within the client script, i.e.

```
from fabric.api import put, run
from fabric.contrib.files import exists

try:
    with cd("/folder1/folder2"):
        put("file1.py")
        run("python file1.py %s" % " ".join([args1, args2, ...]))
except:
    # handle exceptions gracefully on client side
finally:
    try:
        if exists("/folder1/folder2/file1.py"):
            run ("rm -f /folder1/folder2/file1.py")
    except:
        pass
```